# PHP Code will not read on Network Server

Tags: php, wamp

I have a database running on a network server (Ex. if you open My documents, at the bottom on the left navigation bar, you can access networks).

My network server is called \\server.

I have downloaded WAMP to \\server so that I can upload .php files to my server so that it can act as a web server with the address file://server/wamp/[path]/[file].php. This php connects the database to users on the web that go to this address.

I am have my database set, php files complete and uploaded, and port 80 is clear for only WAMP to be used on this server. But my .php files STILL are not read! Can anyone help figure out what is wrong? Does this have to do with the fact that this is not a real address (file://)?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your problem is with the `file:` scheme that you're trying to use, as WAMP is listening on port 80 (HTTP). Try using `http:` in your address.

Comment: This is what I believe to be the issue, too. When I do type in the address, http://server/wamp/[path]/[file].php, the page returns:

"403 Forbidden

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /wamp/[path]/[file].php on this server."

So I was wondering if there is away around this problem?

Comment: The server's service account will need access to the root directory that is being served. Which directory is WAMP using to serve files? That directory will need at least read permissions allowed for the service account, and the address will need to be constructed relative to that directory.

Answer (score -2):

if you are using wamp server then check for all services started if not restart all services and make sure that the wamp icon is green if not then the problem with wamp server.And also check in apache server the php module is mark for this click on green wamp icon and goto apache then in apache modules and at last mark php5_module.